# Windows Phone 8.1 TCP sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, events, tcp, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing a Windows Phone 8.1 chat app and discovered multiple difficulties during programming a socket  interoperability.

The main issue are 'events' on a socket, and main question is: How to subscribe to `OnData` event, e.g. how to detect the event, when data came from the server?

I tried to solve it by direct way: infinite reading from `InputStream`, and that works with 50/50 luck: sometimes that method freeze the UI stream (even the reading method is `async`).

I googled for that issue, because it's a very strange behavior for that important component, and didn't found any solutions for this even on MSDN. At `SO` I found only same solutions like mine, but they also freeze UI flow.

For reference, my app infrastructure is the main app that uses facade class from shared library, the facade class get a generic, that specify concrete behavior (this was done for reason of multiple data transports). For TCP transport, I wrote that:

```
public class TCPTransport : ITransportProvider
{
    private bool _connected { get; set; }
    private StreamSocket _socket { get; set; }

    private DataReader _input { get; set; }

    public TCPTransport()
    {
        _socket = new StreamSocket();
    }

    public async Task<bool> Connect(string host, int port)
    {
        try
        {
            await _socket.ConnectAsync(new HostName(host), port.ToString());

            if (OnConnect != null)
                OnConnect();

            _connected = true;
            _input = new DataReader(_socket.InputStream)
            {
                InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial
            };

            _read();

            return _connected;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("[warn] cant conect to " + host + ":" + port + ". Additional: " + e.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }

    async private void _read()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (!_connected || _socket == null) break;

            uint buffer = await _input.LoadAsync(2048);
            string data = _input.ReadString(buffer);

            if (OnData != null && data.Length != 0)
                OnData(data);
        }
    }

    public async Task<bool> Send(string data)
    {
        if (!_connected) return false;

        try
        {
            await _socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data).AsBuffer());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("[warn] Exception send: " + e.Message);
        }

        return true;
    }

    public bool Close()
    {
        if (!_connected) return false;

        _socket.Dispose();

        return true;
    }

    public Action OnConnect { get; set; }
    public Action<string> OnData { get; set; }
    public Action OnClose { get; set; }
}
```

I suppose that I am wrong about using that solution, but how can I listen to data from server?

Answer (score 0):

For better or worse, the `StreamSocket` API is not designed as an event-driven API; it is designed as an asynchronous API. If you want to raise an event when data is available, use an event, not a delegate:

Here is a trivial example (hard-coded to www.microsoft.com and with no error handling) showing how to simulate the event:

**Note that if you run with the debugger attached, it will temporarily freeze the UI thread. This doesn't occur when not debugging**

```
// Create your own class to hold the data
public class DataReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  public uint DataCount { get; private set; }
  public DataReceivedEventArgs(uint dataCount)
  {
    DataCount = dataCount;
  }
}

// Now inside your MainPage...

bool m_keepReading = false;
bool m_eventHandled = false;
public event TypedEventHandler<MainPage, DataReceivedEventArgs> DataReceived;

// Hook this up to (eg) a Button
private async void StartSockets(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (!m_eventHandled)
    DataReceived += (s, args) => Debug.WriteLine(args.DataCount);
  m_eventHandled = true;

  m_keepReading = true;
  DoSocketTestAsync();
}

// Hook this up to (eg) a Button
private void StopSockets(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  m_keepReading = false;
}

private async Task DoSocketTestAsync()
{
  var socket = new StreamSocket();
  await socket.ConnectAsync(new HostName("www.microsoft.com"), "http");
  var writer = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);
  writer.WriteString("GET /en-us HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: www.microsoft.com\r\n\r\n");
  await writer.StoreAsync();

  ReadSocketAsync(socket);
}

private async void ReadSocketAsync(StreamSocket socket)
{
  while (m_keepReading)
  {
    const uint size = 2048;
    IBuffer buffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(size);
    buffer = await socket.InputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, size,
     InputStreamOptions.Partial);
    var handler = DataReceived; 
    if (handler != null && buffer.Length > 0)
      handler(this, new DataReceivedEventArgs(buffer.Length));
  }
}
```

Now when you click the "start" button, assuming you have a network connection you will see some numbers start appearing in the Debug Output window.

(Also note that using `private` auto-implemented properties doesn't really buy you anything; just make them fields).

Comment: Thank you @peter for reply! I want to subscribe for that event, but in MSDN docs WEREN'T any info about events on `StreamSocket` object. And as I sayed in the question, I tried to emulate that event by inifinite reading from socket, which is a normal behavior on any platform. And, as I sayed, the problem is in random freezeing the UI flow during reading

Comment: Maybe I explain unclean, but in `StreamSocket` class there are NO EVENTS, for which a user code can subscribe. For that issue, there is NO EVENT, which can indice that some data came from the server

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't helpful for me with this issue. As You can see, I tried a simillar solution, but unsuccesfully. I need an option to listen for raw data from socket, because this is the only way to build a chat app. If You know any other way to continously getting data and updating the corresponding UI, please write it. I tried to do it by direct infinite reading, but as was mentioned in question random freeze the UI flow

Comment: for remarks, when I say `freeze UI flow` it means that all after `uint buffer = await _input.LoadAsync(2048);` doesn't executed, and the app stops to react on any UI or other events

Comment: I assume you're running under a debugger? The sockets code will freeze the UI thread when running with the debugger attached, but if you run without then it will be smooth. (I've seen this problem long ago, but can't remember what the cause was...)

Comment: No, I'm not an idiot, freezeing occurs even if app run without attached debugger. Please, write your answers like comments, don't interrupt the discussion by editing answers

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to imply you were "an idiot" -- there is a *significant* difference when debugging even if there are no breakpoints. Please provide a complete program that exhibits the poor behaviour, otherwise we're grasping at straws.